# Do we consider Bitnami to fall under the cPanel close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

It's not *exactly* a cPanel-style system, but it shares the same characteristics - weird, specific, one-click configurations that are pervasive and difficult to debug and tweak.

Is it legitimate to close these under the "no control panels" close reason? I feel like there's been a rise in them recently, and the folks asking almost always have no clue where the configs are, let alone how to modify them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Bitnami stacks are off-topic for a very similar reason to why WAMP/XAMPP/etc stacks are off-topic - they encourage non-standard deployment methodologies, and actively discourage users from actually learning what they are using.

Users that post bitnami-related question should be gently encouraged to either post their question on a product-specific support forum or preferably switch to a more standard application deployment infrastructure.

Comment: Works for me! Thanks.

Comment: Even when they get [upvoted](http://serverfault.com/q/792230/126632) and on the hot list? :) I noticed that you read that one, but didn't touch it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Hah, touché. I read it before I fully internalized my feelings on the issue. :)

Comment: While I totally agree with Bitnami being off-topic I'm not sure that `Bitnami encourages non-standard deployment methodologies` is a good and systematic reason. Who decides what is a standard? Feels a bit arbitrarily. And when SF decides to label a technology as `non-standard` that might have an impact on the chances of a technology to become a new standard. I mean most technologies are kind of non-standard in an early phase.

Comment: @knowhy I think the point of differentiation for me is "does it leave its server owners ignorant of the system's configuration?" If it assists you in putting together a config, that's one thing, but the one-click stuff is typically negative on a long-term maintenance standpoint.

Comment: @ceejayoz But that applies to many systems. To me it seems like many people are using systems like `docker`. `vagrant`, `puppetforge` or `ansible-galaxy` (just to name a few) with the idea that the could avoid to understand how things work.

Comment: @knowhy I'd still argue each of those are significantly more transparent to someone who wants to dig into the config. Looking at https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress as an example, I can't see any obvious way to even figure out what web server the stack you'd be installing includes. `ansible-galaxy` is a bunch of pointers to Github projects with readable `.yml` files - Bitnami is an index of installers.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the current stats I don't think bitnami is much of a problem topic at the moment, so I would be in favour of treating each question on its own merits, rather than issuing a blanket ban.

The [bitnami](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bitnami) tag only lists 10 questions marked as such this year and a search for questions containing bitnami as a keyword (using: [`is:question bitnami`](https://serverfault.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20bitnami) as the search string)  only returns a 113 results, not a huge number.

Roughly half of the questions which mention bitnami have been answered. ([`66 / 113`](https://serverfault.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+bitnami+isanswered%3Ayes))

Only a handful of questions has been down-voted with for ServerFault quite a few even ([`57/113`](https://serverfault.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20bitnami%20score%3a1))  scoring one or more up votes

Comment: Five (not necessarily tagged, but with it in the question text) in the last 24 hours, with maybe one every two weeks prior to that.

Comment: Ultimately, though, I'm not asking for a blanket ban, but I'm asking if it's generally legitimate to say "this is cPanel-style stuff, close" when someone comes around asking for help with Bitnami appliances.

Comment: My search seems to be acting differently from yours as I get only [3 questions](http://serverfault.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20bitnami) over the last month... Odd. - Although the arguments against bitnami as a one-click installer may be similar to those we use against control panels, that existing default close reason may be confusing to the OP without clarification. You can VtC with a custom reason instead as well

Comment: OK, I'll plan to use the cPanel reason with a clarifying comment.

Comment: Agreed. IMHO bitnami questions don't have a place here.

Comment: And do AWS questions have a place here?

Comment: @RyanBabchishin: Yes, many AWS questions are on topic.